# how to run php code which is added dynamically to DOM via JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

so I have this website project where I am about to load content in a content div.

```
<div id="content_wrapper">
  <!-- content goes here -->
</div>
```

and a `content.js` file with

```
var c_index = 'Some cool text stuff<br>' +
              'pretty neat, and also with a<br>' +
              '<img src="image1.png" alt="thumb1">';

var c_service = '/* other stuff in here */';
```

and depending on the click I do:

```
$('#content_wrapper').html(c_index); // or different content vars
```

My question is how I can keep this combined with `php`. For example some info fetched from a database:

```
var c_dynamic = '<?php echo $output["row1"] . ' ' . $output["row2"] ?>';

$('#content_wrapper').html(c_dynamic);
```

Is there anything similar that I can append   `PHP` and then run it without reloading the page.

Comment: why is this downvoted, seriously.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Also, don't ever put PHP in your JS code. Create a PHP script that returns what you need, then use $.ajax to retrieve it and modify the DOM accordingly.

Comment: I would guess because the research effort, the entire point of AJAX is to do what you described (but safer).

Comment: Yeah it's called ajax.

Comment: @TylerMarien thanks for your approach. I know what AJAX is guys, the only thing I'm asking is, if it is somehow possible to tell the PHP parser render something if its added

Comment: You have to clearly -- in your mind -- draw a distinction between client-side code and server-side code. **Server-side code (PHP) gets executed at the server; client-side code (JS) gets executed in your browser(client).** Once that's clear, understanding why you must use [**ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) is child's play :)

Comment: I don't get the down votes without comment thing either. Tell people why you down voted so they can learn. Anyways, I agree with Tyler. You will want to pull the data in with Ajax. Php is server side and will basically fill in the JavaScript on page load and then will need to be reloaded via page refresh for new content. Ajax will call the server side code and put it in the JavaScript without a page reload.

Comment: @nwolybug thanks, thats basically what I needed to know. The question was about if theres a trick or similar not more.

Comment: The "anything similar" and better is ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you are looking for http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php, but even php agrees that it is a terrible idea.  If it is data that you have passed down originally and are just needing to display later, store it in a javascript var and access it when needed, otherwise as mentioned in the comments to your question, make an ajax call to retrieve it when needed.

Comment: thank you, thats a good point about storing the `PHP` jquery in a variable first, and then access it later. This works entirely with what I try to do.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't. Your PHP code has finished executing before the JavaScript starts. What you see on the screen isn't PHP code, it is the output of PHP code. The interpreter doesn't run that, and won't run anything you add to it.

There could be some trick I don't know, but I'm betting that you can't do this.

An alternate way to do what you want might be to call a PHP script from within your JavaScript that sends back some JSON. The PHP script in question would run a database query for you, and send back the information you want to present to the user as JSON. Then you could insert the information retrieved into the DOM.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

That function should come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this with Ajax: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax

You cant set a php variable after the page has loaded.